# Close event for applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I have a `JApplet` that adds a `JPanel`.  I play some music in this, but when I close the web browser Java is still running and playing music.

I couldn't find anything on this, but is there a way to override or catch the close event?  I'd like to do a `music.stop()` or other such housecleaning to try and to get it to shutdown in a more graceful manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void destroy()
```

> Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this applet that it is being reclaimed and that it should destroy any resources that it has allocated.

```
void stop()
```

> Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this applet that it should stop its execution.