# When using Processing in Java, how do you exit out of an applet?

Tags: java, processing

I wrote a program inside `public void draw()` for a processing `applet`. Is there a way to close the applet completely after the program has finished running?

Such as `applet.close`?

I know this is possible with a direct `java` `applet`, but I don't know how to do it when using processing.

Comment: Have you tried `System.exit(0);`

Comment: In what context would you want to close the applet directly?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, try

```
System.exit(0);
```

The following link though goes over some limitations that might apply to you.

[How to close java Applet through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507108/how-to-close-java-applet-through-code)

Here are some other options:
[Close event for applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516744/close-event-for-applet)

Including:

```
void destroy();
void stop();
```